# What this statement is really saying to prove one Real number has missed the bijection with Integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

In a *Combinatorics* text, I find this:

> Not all infinite sets have the same cardinality. Consider the set of
>   all integers and the set of all reals. Assume that the set of reals
>   can be put in one-to-one-onto correspondence with the integers. **Then
>   consider the real number whose ith digit after the decimal is the ith
>   digit of the ith real plus 5 mod 10.** This real number cannot be in
>   correspondence with any integer, since it differs from every real that
>   has been mapped to an integer. From this we conclude that the reals
>   cannot be placed in one-to-one correspondence with the integers.

What the bolded text is really saying to prove that one real number has been missed from mapping? Can you please explain the bolded sentence? I want to know how exactly has that real number missed the mapping.

Comment: Yes, and that happens **whatever** the mapping was. So the mapping cannot be a bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. This is called Cantor's diagonal argument. For ANY mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$ you can think of, using this argument, you can find a real number the mapping missed.

The ANY part is really important, because you cannot say that ok, if I missed $x$, I'll just add $x$ and now I covered all the examples. The problem with this is that after you do this, you have created a new mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$, to which, again, you can apply the argument.

Okay, look at it this way. You come rusing to my office, shouting you just discovered the mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $(0,1)$. I ask you to show it to me, and you display it to me. It looks like this:

```
a1 = 0.15333524632394823876423498029343...
a2 = 0.18736120389038483789102374u32908...
a3 = 0.28193719283789900000000000000000...
a4 = 0.12372937890483092848237496324908...
```

I can easily look at your sequence and use the argument in your question to produce a number. It starts with $0.$, then on the first decimal place, i will put $1+5=6$ because the first digit of $a_1$ is $1$. On the second place, I put $8+5\mod 10=3$ because the second digit of $a_2$ is $8$. I have thus produced a number that is not on your list:

```
0.6362...
```

The real magic here is that there is no way you can escape my argument. In a way, imagine the set of ALL mappings from $\mathbb N$ to $(0,1)$. The proof above shows that EVERY element in this set has SOME real number it misses.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it how exactly this argument is smart?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
9 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 1 & \cdots\\
- & - & - & - & - & \cdots\\
4 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 2 & \cdots\\
5 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 6 & \cdots\\
6 & 7 & 3 & 5 & 1 & \cdots\\
0 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 9 & \cdots\\
2 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 6 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\end{array}$

The upper number will not be one of the numbers below, since $9\neq 4$ (so it cannot be the first number), $7\neq 2$ (so it cannot be the second number) et cetera.